# SML Signature fn: String -> String -> String

Tags: string, sml, signature, higher-order-functions

I am trying to have the following signature for a function `compute`:

```
val compute = fn: string -> string -> string
```

I know how to use higher order functions by introducing a let in the function, however the result might be changed into

```
val compute = fn: string -> (fn: string -> string) -> string.
```

I need the signature to be correct. Can anymore explain this to me and it would be much appreciated if you can give one or two examples.

Comment: What is the definition of compute that is giving you the incorrect function signature?

Comment: The question actually has nothing to do with functionality of compute. I figured it out eventually. The difference between the first one and the second one is the first signature allow me to pass two strings for the function one by one, having one of the function as a variable : ) The example will be      compute "test1" "test2".   Thanks still!

Comment: @angerhang, can you share your answer?  You can answer your own questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though

```
fn: string -> string -> string
```

and

```
fn: string -> (fn: string -> string) -> string
```

both take two strings as input and have one string as output. The operation is different inside the function. The first one, take one string as input, and perhaps have a local function that also take the second string as have one string as output. (two strings in the parameters in the local function)

the second one will have a higher order function which one string as input for the let in function.